# Bootstrap stateful button not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get my bootstrap button to show "loading..." while some time consuming function (fetching data from an external source) is executed.
Interestingly, the reference implementation using `setTimeout` works perfectly.

It seems to me that somehow the `$(button).button('loading')` command is executed only after the function closes and the setTimeout works around that by waiting in the background. How can I replicate the result of the setTimeout command with code that actually does something?

[Jsfiddle demonstrating my problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/kvsh7LuL/2/)

here is my HTML code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="comb" data-loading-text="Loading..." autocomplete="off" onclick="comb()">Combinations</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="timer" data-loading-text="Loading..." autocomplete="off" onclick="timer()">Set Timeout</button>
```

and here the javascript:

```
function combinations(str) {
    var fn = function (active, rest, a) {
        if (!active && !rest) return;
        if (!rest) {
            a.push(active);
        } else {
            fn(active + rest[0], rest.slice(1), a);
            fn(active, rest.slice(1), a);
        }
        return a;
    }
    return fn("", str, []);
}

function comb() {
    var btn = $('#comb').button('loading');
    console.log(combinations('abcdefghijklmnopqrs'));//this is a function that takes a lot of time (~5s) to execute
    btn.button('reset');
}

function timer() {
    var btn = $('#timer').button('loading');
    setTimeout(function () {
        btn.button('reset');
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Are you doing something asynchronous and wanting the button to not "reset" until it's done?

Comment: I don't think that what I am doing is asynchronous. I get the same result (the button not changing its state) pretty much whatever I do inside the function. The only thing that works is if I use setTimeout but that does not do anything useful... In fact, I think I need to find a way to make my command execute asynchronously like setTimeout does.

Comment: @Archer: I also tried to run the `button('reset')` command after my code by wrapping my code in a function that returns jQuery's `$.Deferred().resolve();` and then calling my code like this: `wrapper().done(function(){btn.button('reset');});` [here is the updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvsh7LuL/3/)

Comment: Okay, thanks - it's the opposite of what I was thinking then, and yes, you've got below exactly what I was going to suggest.  It's because the UI isn't getting chance to update before your function runs, and then your function is blocking further execution until it's completed.  You won't come across this often, but what you've done is the best way around it (currently).

Comment: @Archer btw. thanks for your help, answering your first reply got me on the right track ;-)

Comment: No problem - glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a working solution which is something of a hack. I would still appreciate better suggestions and/or an explanatinos what is going on.

Here is the HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="comb" data-loading-text="Loading..." autocomplete="off" onclick="comb()">Combinations</button>
```

and here the working javascript (basically I wrapped my code in a setTimeout command with a very short timeout:

```
function combinations(str) {
    var fn = function (active, rest, a) {
        if (!active && !rest) return;
        if (!rest) {
            a.push(active);
        } else {
            fn(active + rest[0], rest.slice(1), a);
            fn(active, rest.slice(1), a);
        }
        return a;
    }
    return fn("", str, []);
}

function comb() {
    var btn = $('#comb').button('loading');
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(combinations('abcdefghijklmnopqrs'));
        btn.button('reset');
    },100);
}
```

it seems to me, that the code I was executing was preventing bootstraps javascript (or jQuery) from changing the button state until it was finished. The setTimeout command now gives bootstraps javascript the time to change the button state before my code is executed. I still find this strange and would appreciate an explanation.

Edit:

[Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kvsh7LuL/7/)

Edit2: I realized that a timeout of 100 ms is safer than just 10ms because some slower devices/browsers might not be able to rebuild the page in 10ms. I updated the code/jsfiddle accordingly.

Edit3: With the help from peterblazejevicz over at [the Bootstrap Github issue tracker](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15276), I found this elegant solution using a promise:

```
function comb() {
    var btn = $('#promise').button('loading');
    var request = $.ajax('/');
    request.done(function (data) {
        console.log(combinations('abcdefghijklmnopqrs'));
    });
    request.always(function () {
        btn.button('reset');
    });
}
```

[Here is the updated and final jsfiddle demonstrating the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kvsh7LuL/11/)